# Incorrect syntax near 'Root' SQL returning XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

How to correct the following query in order to return an xml.
I am getting the following error "Line 14: Incorrect syntax near 'Root'.
" How  to fix this?

```
declare @v_CurrentDate datetime
set @v_CurrentDate = '2016-07-28'

if exists (select 1
from mydb.dbo.Orders
where OrderDate = @v_CurrentDate)
begin

SELECT 'mydb' AS Client, PrimaryKey, Ship_Status, OrderDate, ApprovedDate, AcknowledgeDate, ShipToSiteName, AntShipDate
FROM mydb.dbo.Orders
WHERE (Ship_Status = 'Acknowledged')
ORDER BY PrimaryKey DESC
for xml auto, type, elements, Root('Orders') 

end
else
select cast('<NoRecords>No order records available for this date.</NoRecords>' as xml)
```

Comment: Tried it, and it works for me. SQL Server 2008 R2. Try running `SELECT Client FROM Orders FOR xml auto, type, elements, Root('Orders')`

Comment: with my query it is still not working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to supply an example of the failing query.

Screenshot the SQL Server Management Studio when you run:

```
create database TestFoo; 
go
use TestFoo
go
create table users (userid int); select userid from users for xml auto, type, elements, root('foo');
go 
use master
go
drop database TestFoo
```

[image]